# Referencing a the index object's name in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, indexing

How can R report the actual name `i`, when using it to name columns and lists in a for loop.

For example, using the following data:

`z <- data.frame(x= c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c("a", "b", "v", "d", "e"))`

When I reference `i` from the loop when creating the columns it names it `i` as the column names.

```
a_final <- NULL
for(i in z$x){
  print(data.frame(i = z$y))

}
```

Instead, I'd like the columns to be named by the value of each `i` in the loop, instead.

I'd like the results to look something like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
a a a a a a
b b b b b b 
c c c c c c
d d d d d d
e e e e e e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a matrix with data from `z$y` and dimensions same as `nrow(z)` and convert it into dataframe.

```
as.data.frame(matrix(z$y, ncol = nrow(z), nrow = nrow(z)))

#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  a  a  a  a  a
#2  b  b  b  b  b
#3  c  c  c  c  c
#4  d  d  d  d  d
#5  e  e  e  e  e
```

---

We can also use `replicate`

```
as.data.frame(replicate(nrow(z), z$y))
```